# I have no intellisense with views in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I have no intellisense of any kind in visual studio..

Here is my basic view:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "MakeMenu";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model PArticle.Models.Menu
<h2>MakeMenu</h2>


<table> 
<tr>
<td>
 Menu:    @Html.Editor("menu")
 <td>

 <td>
   Submenu:    @Html.Editor("submenu")
 </td>

 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td align="center" colspan="2">

   </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

It doesnt matter what I type, intellisense never works..why is that?

Comment: When you type `@Html.` in a view don't you get Intellisense for the available helpers?

Comment: did you install mvc4 beta? Do you have any other project in your solution mixing 3 and 4? Ironically this just happened to me when I installed 4, although im not sure if its related. working on a solution now.

Comment: Do you have resharper installed by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please verify "Auto List Members" is checked for AllLanguages and C# in VS2010 => Tools =>Options => Text Editors

[image]

Comment: I checked this..but no intellisense whatsoever

Comment: I think the solution would be to reinstall visual studio :!(

Comment: if its specific to MVC I dont think a reinstall of VS will do much for you.

Answer (score 0):

first re install mvc engine and if not solve reinstall the vs
maybe solve your problem