# visual studio 2010 html/Razor intellisense doesnt work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed mvc3 and the html intellisense stopped working.

This wasnt the situation when I had mvc2 installed.

When I type this @... nothing works in this view, for example.

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "MakeMenu";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>MakeMenu</h2>
```

I tried going to tools->options->text editor and change whatever i could , but nothing worked..I also reinstalled visual studio and mvc, but that didnt work too..

I have no intellisense or any other tool to help me with producing and correcting code in the views that I create!!

Comment: I fully understand your frustration but please don't keep asking the same question multiple times. Possible duplicate of [I have no intellisense with views in visual studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442818/i-have-no-intellisense-with-views-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: It is ...But, there is no way to solve it..I googled..and if no one answers my question,,it means I have to reinstall windows

Comment: once again: I understand your frustration but there are rules on Stack Overflow that you are invited to respect them if you are using this site. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and please don't post duplicate questions because they will be closed anyway. I invite you to delete this question now.

Comment: I dont understand why it happens. Can you please make sure you have selected Razor as the view engine , while creating the project.

Comment: I think I installed some extension that screwed up the razor engine..It doesnt work..I think I will reinstall my os

Comment: mvc 2 works..but mvc 3 is corrupt

Comment: Have you tried resetting your Visual Studio preferences back to the default to see if that helps at all? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Razor Intellisense work with **Razor Editor**

Check if it is selected as default editor, For this do

- Right Click on view file (.cshtml)
- Select Open With...
- Check Razor editor Select as default
- if not, uninstall mvc3 from control panel reinstall it.

Again check files open in Razor Editor. I have done this and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried add in razor block 'this.' keywork?
Ctrl+J also not hepls?